# Changing value of variable in Highcharts selection event in angular

Tags: angular, highcharts

To begin with here is a code extract in angular 7+ using Highcharts API:

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit{
    seek: boolean = false;
    exampleChart;
    public options = {
        chart:{
            zoomType: 'x',
            events: {
                selection: function(event){
                    this.seek = true;
                    console.log(this.seek); // outputs to true
                }
            }
        },
        xAxis:{
            type:'datetime'
        }
        series:{
            // given relevant datetime values
        }
    };

    constructor(){}
    ngOnInit{
        this.exampleChart = this.options;
    }

    onClick(){
        console.log(this.seek); // outputs false
    }

}
```

Scenario : First i am selecting a particular portion  in the graph and then clicking the button

Since the **zoomtype** is on ***x-axis***, i can zoom in/out and the **selection event** gets fired with the correct event value. However i am also changing the value of **seek** in that event to be *true*. This change does not get reflected to the original **seek** , as on pressing the button and calling the onClick() function the value of seek in the console outputs to false. I do not know why it is happening like that and how to get the correct value.

Comment: This might be cause of wrong context. Did u try an arrow function? ```selection: (event) => { this.seek = true; }```

Comment: Thank you man. Your solution works. But how did you come up with that, and what syntax was i using, the AngularJS one?

Comment: this is a weird part about functions in js, as they have their own this context. Arrow functions dont. regards

Comment: ok thanks man. Will keep that in mind.

Comment: One thing i wanted to know however, like since the normal functions have their own context, does this mean that this in( this.seek ) inside the normal function is kind of defined on its own, and outside the variable just takes whatever value is assigned to it out of that scope? i mean, how come since it is assigned a true value inside the normal function, the assignment is of no use later?

Comment: it works like an own context that is only reachable inside that function. It has nothing to do with your component class context. Thats why you dont see a mutated value to true.

Comment: To reach out to your component class context, you would have to pass component clas context on chartcreation like this: let that = this. This thread explains it more detailed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44745833/how-to-call-typescript-function-inside-high-chart-click-event

Comment: Hello @sagat, can you help me with this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61725741/uncaught-typeerror-shown-in-karma-when-unit-testing-in-angular and also with this :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61719672/checking-for-correctly-calculated-combined-values-while-unit-testing-in-angular

Comment: Hello @sagat, can you help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62095430/callback-and-testing-highcharts

Comment: Hey @sagat, thanks man. It did help a lot. Can you upvote this question also :). So that it reaches more number of people.

Comment: Hello @sagat, can you help me with this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62394625/unit-testing-asynchronous-code-including-setinterval-in-angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer as suggested by @sagat :

```
public options = {
        chart:{
            zoomType: 'x',
            events: {
                selection: (event)=> {
                    this.seek = true;
                    console.log(this.seek); // outputs to true
                }
            }
        },
        xAxis:{
            type:'datetime'
        }
        series:{
            // given relevant datetime values
        }
    };


constructor(){}
    ngOnInit{
        this.exampleChart = this.options;
    }

    onClick(){
        console.log(this.seek); // outputs true
    }
```

Thank you.